# Set variable from function

Tags: angular, typescript

This may be an easy question/answer, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it: 
I am validating fields with a function using AbstractControl:

```
errorVar: boolean = false

function(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: string } | null {
 // validation if 'test' is true or not goes here
 if(test) {
  let errorMessageText: "test"
  return {'errorText': errorMessageText};
 }
return null;
}
```

Besides the `errorText` I want the function to also set the variable `errorVar` to `true` and to `false` if the function returns null.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: If I try to set the variable inside the function it comes back as "undefined is not an object. So I'm fairly new to this and can't figure out why. So my idea was to have the function return the variable

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
  errorVar: boolean = false

  function(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: string } | null {
    // validation if 'test' is true or not goes here
    if (test) {
      this.errorVar = true;
      let errorMessageText:
        return { 'errorText': errorMessageText };
    }

    this.errorVar = false;
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Nope, tried that first of course. It comes back "undefined is not an object"

Comment: Is `errorVar` defined within the context of a `class`?

Comment: yes, it is - it's a reactive form and the variable definition and function is inside the export class

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several problems

- your `errorVar` should be declared using `var` or `let` so you can set it in the function via a closure
- your `errorMessageText` variable must be set using `=` and not `:`

like this:

```
var errorVar: boolean = false;

function(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: string } | null {
    // validation if 'test' is true or not goes here
    if(test) {
        errorVar = true;
        let errorMessageText: string ="test";
        return {'errorText': errorMessageText};
    }
    errorVar = false;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not why it's not working. The `errorVar: boolean = false`  was meant as a pointer that I have declared the variable earlier in the class; the function is a representation what I want to achieve, not a functioning piece of code. Not that I can explain it, but rest assured, I have about 20 other declarations that work just fine this way. ...and to your second point, TypeScript let's you define the variable type by using a colon after the name.

Comment: Well, I tested my code on [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). `let errorMessageText: "test"` did not work (`errorMessageText`was undefined), but `let errorMessageText= "test"` did.

Comment: Concerning the "pointer" thing, what you can do is pass an object `{ errorMessageText:"" }` as parameter, and modify its property inside the function.

Comment: Of course it didn't, because as I said before, you define the type of the variable with the colon ":" and write it with the equal sign "=". So in this example I am setting `errorMessageText` as type string.... but all that is beside the point, because the function properly returns `errorMessageText`, what I need is that the function returns a SECOND variable!

Comment: Ok, this was a typo error. Could it be that you have a problem of `this` binding that prevents you from settings `errorVar` (if it's declared in a class)? In that case, you could  bind explicitly by passing `myFunction.bind(myInstance)` instead of `myFunction`.  Anyway, good luck for your problem.